# Can POST and GET be combined within a single input type?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post, get

I have a form running a shopping cart style application on my site. To add items, I POST values to a form using a submit button. To remove items, I have to use a GET command.

What I want to do is to limit the selection possibilities - as you select one option, others are removed. For instance, if I have three options: Apples, Oranges, Bananas you are only able to select one.

Apples 
Oranges
Bananas

If you select Apples, I want to post the value "Apples" whilst using a GET command to remove "Bananas" and "Oranges".

Currently I am doing this to post the values:

```
<form method="post">
   <fieldset>
       <input type="hidden" name="jcartToken" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['jcartToken'];?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="Apples" />
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Apples" />
        <input type="hidden" name="color" value="red" />
        <input type="hidden" name="shape" value="round" />
        <div id="apples" >
            <input type="submit" name="my-add-button" class="add" value="&nbsp"/>&nbsp Apples
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And to remove the items I do this:

```
<a href="index.php?jcartRemove[]=Bananas&jcartRemove[]=Oranges">remove Bananas and Oranges</a>
```

Is there a way to do both at the same time? I have tried doing an onclick event like this:

```
<div id="Apples" >
    <input type="submit" name="my-add-button" class="add" value="&nbsp" onclick="location.href='index.php?jcartRemove[]=Bananas&jcartRemove[]=Oranges';" />&nbsp Apples
</div>
```

and I have also tried to use an action at the start of the form

But neither of these work - they will still submit the new item, but will not remove the item. Any idea of a good way to do both together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yes, but it's a hack:

```
<form method="post" action="foo.php?x=y">
  <input type="text" name="a" value="b" />
</form>
```

If the form is set to POST, then any `<input>` and `<textarea>` within the form will go as POST data, but any query strings you place into the `action`'s url will show up at the server as GET data:

```
 $_GET['x'] -> 'y'
 $_POST['a'] => 'b'
 $_POST['x'] => undefined index
```

But note that clicking a link that's inside a `<form>` does NOT submit the form. it's like clicking any other link and will just go to the new address.

Comment: I have tried this - <form method="post" action="index.php?jcartRemove[]=Bananas&jcartRemove[]=Oranges"> it does not work. The link included works as a stand-alone <a href> link but doesn't send GET commands like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_REQUEST`. As per the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), quoted as follows:

> An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE

As above, you can then use the following hack:

```
<form method="post" action="foo.php?x=y">
  <input type="text" name="a" value="b" />
</form>
```

**EDIT:** If both of the GET and POST requests work individually, it is possible that your PHP is where the problem lies - You haven't posted it, so I can't see where the issue could be. You could just put together some javascript to fire the remove request then fire the add request when clicked:

```
jQuery("input[name|='my-add-button']").click(function() {
  var addform = jQuery(this);
  event.preventDefault();
  $.get("index.php?jcartRemove[]=Bananas&jcartRemove[]=Oranges", function(data) {
    addform.submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: I think it is worthwhile to mention the [`request_order`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order) directive in php.ini because it will have a significant impact on using `$_REQUEST`

Comment: So would you do the request like: form method="request"?

Comment: no. you still POSt or GET in the form. php will simply aggregate post,get,cookies into the single $_REQUEST.

Comment: Thanks. So that still leaves me having to submit a POST and GET data with a single button click which doesn't seem to be working. I still want to wrap the form around a <a href> or make the action="url" solution